# Puppet : how to resolve "file_line" multi match patterns

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to change configuration file using puppet.

This is my test.txt file that i want to change :

```
[default]
#puppet=no
abc=123

[nova]
#puppet=no
```

I want to change "#puppet=no" to "puppet=yes" **only on [default] tab.**

This is my test.pp for two version :

```
file_line{"someline":
   path => '/root/openstack-puppet/computenode/nova/test.txt',
   match => '[default]\n#puppet',
   line => 'puppet=ok'
}
```

This one failed to find match pattern, so it just add "puppet=ok" at the end of file.

```
file_line{"someline":
   path => '/root/openstack-puppet/computenode/nova/test.txt',
   match => '#puppet',
   line => 'puppet=ok'
}
```

This one failed because of multi match pattern problem.

I tried Augeas also, but I can't find how to uncomment using Augeas.

Somebody please help me with this problem!!

=========================================================================

I run this code :

```
file_line { 'someline':
  path     => '/root/openstack-puppet/computenode/nova/test.txt',
  after    => '\[default\]',
  multiple => 'false',
  match    => '#puppet',
  line     => 'puppet=ok',
}
```

But when I run with "puppet apply" it still makes same error :

```
Error: More than one line in file '/root/openstack-puppet/computenode/nova/test.txt' matches pattern '#puppet'
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/File_line[someline]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: More than one line in file '/root/openstack-puppet/computenode/nova/test.txt' matches pattern '#puppet'
```

**I think that 'after' attribute cannot applied when 'match' attribute is defined.**

When I erase 'match' attribute, it works, but it didn't replace original string('#puppet=no').

It just added new line after [default] like this :

```
[default]
puppet=ok
#puppet=no
abc=123
dedd=0


[nova]
#puppet=no
```

**So the issues still remain, how can I erase(or replace) the string '#puppet=no'
only on [default] tab??**

Answer (score 2):

The file looks like it fits with the ini file format so a better solution would be to use the inifile resource type  https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppetlabs/inifile

```
ini_setting { "sample setting":
  ensure  => present,
  path    => '/root/openstack-puppet/computenode/nova/test.txt',
  section => 'default',
  setting => 'puppet',
  value   => 'yes',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `after` attribute will solve this problem for you. Taking your second resource and cleaning up some, we have:

```
file_line { 'someline':
  path     => '/root/openstack-puppet/computenode/nova/test.txt',
  match    => '#puppet',
  line     => 'puppet=ok'
  after    => '[default]',
  multiple => false,
}
```

Notice I also added the `multiple` attribute to safeguard against changing more than just the line you want to change.

The reason your first resource would have issues is threefold. First, `file_line` requires that your `line` attribute have a successful regexp match against the `match` attribute, which is not true in your case. Second, putting `[default]` in the `match` attribute means that `[default]` would be removed from your file if the resource succeeded as you wrote it. Third, you need to escape `[]` in your regexp, so it would look like `\[default\]` if you wanted to go that route (and you do not for the first two reasons given).

Comment: Thanks for helping me!! However, I think there are still some issues... Your code makes some errors... I added those issues on my question. Please check it.

Comment: @BlakStar Based on your edit above, I see that you are confused by my answer and need some further information on what these attributes are doing in `file_line`. Please reference the documentation at https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib/types. The quick fix is to use the resource I gave above. There is no reason to escape `[]` in a literal string in the `after` attribute.

Comment: Your code(I just added ',' at 'line' attribute since it makes syntax error) still makes same error which I added on my question(multi match). I checked file_line attributes on this docs : https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib. Docs says that 'after' is just indicate  where the 'line' will be added so I think it will not affect to 'match' attribute. So I guess your code also makes multi match error for this reason.

Comment: @BlakStar Hopefully you figure out to just use my answer and then understand how it works from my answer and the docs. Good luck!

Comment: @BlakStar is correct here, `after` is only for where to insert the line, not where to `match` it. So I believe the above answer is incorrect as it will match the line `#puppet` outside or before the `[default]` block. And if you have the line in 2 blocks with `multiple=> false` you will also get an error message saying the line was matched multiple times, even with the `after`. This makes sense as `after` would also not protect you from clobbering the option in another block after default. regex parsing does not understand ini, you will need something like `augeas` instead of `file_line`

Comment: I concur. This solution does not work for the described issue. The correct answer is to use ini_setting instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try it.

```
include stdlib
file_line{"someline":
   ensure => 'present',
   after => 'default',
   multiple => false,
   path => '/root/openstack-puppet/computenode/nova/test.txt',
   line => 'puppet=ok',
}
```

Comment: Other than by omitting any explanation, how is this meaningfully different from the existing, upvoted, five-year-old answer?